# How to edit some extends block in jinja2?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a base template named *main.html*:

```
<ul>
  <li>index</li>
  <li>about</li>
  <li>contacts</li>
</ul>
```

And I have a template *index.html*, which has:

```
{% extends "main.html" %}
```

How I can add class atributes into `<li>` tags depending on named heir?

For example, if *index.html* extends *main.html*, then I add `class="active"` to first `<li>`, if *about.html* extends *main.html*, then I add `class="active"` to second `<li>` .... and so on.

How I can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are kinda two solution to this:

the first way is defining a macro and calling it from child pages(not the inherited `main` page) which contain information to make which `<li>` active.

like :

```
{% macro menu(active) %}

<ul>
  {% if active == 'index' %}<li class="active">{% else %}<li>{%endif%}index</li>
  {% if active == 'about' %}<li class="active">{% else %}<li>{%endif%}about</li>
  {% if active == 'contacts' %}<li class="active">{% else %}<li>{%endif%}contacts</li>
</ul>

{% endmacro %}
```

and use it as :

```
{% from 'macro.html' import menu %}

{{ macro('index') }} #in index.html
{{ macro('about') }} #in about.html
{{ macro('contacts') }} #in contacts.html
```

another ways is using the magical `g` variable. in your view functions define which item should be the active one and put in the `g` variable. like:

```
from flask import g

app.route('/about')
def about():
  ...
  g.active_menu_item = 'about'

  ...

  return render_template('about.html')
```

and your `about.html`(index and contacts too) inherits from `main.html', so the codes that render menu of`main.html`should consider`g.active_menu_item` into account. like:

main.html :

```
<ul>
  {% if g.active_menu_item == 'index' %}<li class="active">{% else %}<li>{%endif%}index</li>
  {% if g.active_menu_item == 'about' %}<li class="active">{% else %}<li>{%endif%}about</li>
  {% if g.active_menu_item == 'contacts' %}<li class="active">{% else %}<li>{%endif%}contacts</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way could be to keep the main.html as is and override it at the child level (about.html etc) by calling super ? I have not tested this code but something like:

### main.html

```
{% block menu_bar %}
<ul>
  <li>index</li>
  <li>about</li>
  <li>contacts</li>
</ul>
{% endblock %}
```

### about.html

```
{% block menu_bar %}
<li class="active">about</li>
{{ super() }}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

**menu.html**

```
<ul>
  <li class="{% if active_menu == 'index' %}active{% endif %}">index</li>
  <li class="{% if active_menu == 'about' %}active{% endif %}">about</li>
  <li class="{% if active_menu == 'contacts' %}active{% endif %}"contacts</li>
</ul>
```

**index.html**

```
{% extends "main.html" %}

{% include "menu.html" with active_menu='index' %}
```

**about.html**

```
{% extends "main.html" %}

{% include "menu.html" with active_menu='about' %}
```

**contacts.html**

```
{% extends "main.html" %}

{% include "menu.html" with active_menu='contacts' %}
```